# Ember: How to keep model errors?

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on add user form. There are three required fields (first name, last name and email). I have server side validation.

For example I have following response and following view:

```
{"errors":{
    "lastName":["NullableFieldValue"],
    "email":["UnexpectedFieldValue"]
    }
}
```

[image]

Simplified template:

```
{{#each error in errors.messages}}
    {{error}}<br/>
{{/each}}
<span>Name</span>   
{{input classBinding="errors.firstName:has-error :form-control" placeholder="First" value=firstName}}
{{input classBinding="errors.lastName:has-error :form-control" placeholder="Last" value=lastName}}
<span>Email</span>  
{{input classBinding="errors.email:has-error :form-control" placeholder="Input Email Address" value=email}}
```

The problem is in following: If I change the field with error (or even focus and unfocus field) the error will disappear. How can I keep the errors in fields until next submit?

Comment: Could you provide JSBIN? a little hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to override `DS.Errors` if you're going to do that, or when an error is received from the server, create your own errors object and append it to the record.  `DS.Errors` observes all properties on the model, and in the event of a change, clears the corresponding errors.  This is intended behavior, as most validation implementations assume that the error is to be rectified if the value is changed.

Another note--the `errors` hash is generally meant to have human errors, not server errors or error codes, so that might have some influence on your implementation.